# Salesforce marketing cloud issue

Tags: exacttarget, ampscript

I tried to re-connect Marketing cloud with salesforce and this doesn´t work. Error: There was an error communicating with Salesforce, verify your connected app is set up properly and try again.

Comment: did you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

I have hit this issue while working in SFMC support and while performing MC Consulting work. This issue was most likely caused by a connected app not properly set up on the SFDC side and the user added to the connected application. I also know this is a necro post, but it is still an issue that happens occasionally. I hope this helps.

be sure to follow these steps the following is from step 11 in the attached link

- In the Sales or Service cloud, click Setup.
- Search for Connected Apps in the Quick Find box and click Connected Apps.
- Click Salesforce Marketing Cloud.
- Click Edit.
- Under Permitted Users, select Admin approved users are pre-authorized.
- Under IP Relaxation, select Relax IP restrictions.
- Under Refresh Token Policy, select Immediately expire refresh token.
- Click Save.
- From Setup, search for Permission Sets in the Quick Find box and click Permission  Sets.
- Create a new permission set.

> NOTE This permission set is used to associate users to the Salesforce Marketing >Cloud Connected App and can remain empty.

- Name the permission set, for example, Marketing Cloud Connected App.
- Validate the auto-generated API, which is generated using the permission set name.
- Save the changes.
- Click the name of the newly created permission set.
- Click Manage Assignments.
- Click Add Assignments.
- Select the users who need access to the Connected App, typically all users with access to Marketing Cloud Connect.
- Click Assign.
- Click Done.
- From Setup, search for Connected Apps in the Quick Find box and click Connected Apps.
- Click Salesforce Marketing Cloud.
- Click Manage Permission Sets.
- Select the newly created permission set.
- Click Save.

source https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_upgrade_to_connected_app_authentication.htm&type=5